# How to count the results of a where clause in order to calculate a proportion a MYSQL select clause?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm starting out with this query, which gives me back 8 records with a "claimed" status. I'm looking to see if any of the addresses in the `invites-from-address` column are different from that in the `moves-from-address` column :

```
SELECT i.id, i.company_id, i.status,  
  ia_f.base_street as "invites-from-address", a_f.base_street as "moves-from-address", 
  ia_t.base_street as "invites-to-address", a_t.base_street as "moves-to-address", i.`mover_first_name`, 
  i.mover_last_name, i.`to_address_id`

FROM invites i
JOIN moves m ON i.id = m.`claimed_invite_id`
JOIN `invite_addresses` ia_f ON ia_f.id = i.`from_address_id`
JOIN addresses a_f ON a_f.id = m.from_address_id

JOIN `invite_addresses` ia_t ON ia_t.id = i.to_address_id
JOIN addresses a_t ON a_t.id = m.to_address_id

WHERE i.`company_id` = 1040345
GROUP BY id
```

What I'm trying to do in this query below is to create an `average_discrepancy` column on the fly that shows the proportion of addresses that differ between `invites-from-address` and `moves-from-address`. I was able to successfully check for address discrepancies by using a `WHERE` clause that checks that `ia_f.base_street` is not equal to `a_f.base_street` (which are aliased to the columns `invites-from-address` and `moves-from-address` respectively) but when I put this `WHERE` clause inside the `count` function in my `SELECT` cause it doesn't work. Is it because I can't place a `WHERE` clause inside a `SELECT` or a `count` function or both? And is there also a problem with trying to divide the results of two calls to the `count` function in my `SELECT` clause ?

```
SELECT i.id, i.company_id, i.status, 
  count(WHERE ia_f.base_street != a_f.base_street)/count(i.status="claimed") as "average_discrepancy", 
  ia_f.base_street as "invites-from-address", a_f.base_street as "moves-from-address", 
  ia_t.base_street as "invites-to-address", a_t.base_street as "moves-to-address",
  i.`mover_first_name`, 
  i.mover_last_name, i.`to_address_id`

FROM invites i
JOIN moves m ON i.id = m.`claimed_invite_id`
JOIN `invite_addresses` ia_f ON ia_f.id = i.`from_address_id`
JOIN addresses a_f ON a_f.id = m.from_address_id

JOIN `invite_addresses` ia_t ON ia_t.id = i.to_address_id
JOIN addresses a_t ON a_t.id = m.to_address_id

WHERE i.`company_id` = 1040345

AND i.status = "claimed"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this into a SUM instead of a COUNT.  Something like this would do the trick:

```
 SELECT i.id, i.company_id, i.status, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ia_f.base_street != a_f.base_street THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/ SUM(CASE WHEN i.status='claimed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'average_discrepancy', 
  ia_f.base_street as 'invites-from-address', 
  a_f.base_street as 'moves-from-address', 
  ia_t.base_street as 'invites-to-address', 
  a_t.base_street as 'moves-to-address',
  i.mover_first_name, 
  i.mover_last_name, 
  i.to_address_id

FROM invites i
JOIN moves m ON i.id = m.claimed_invite_id
JOIN invite_addresses ia_f ON ia_f.id = i.from_address_id
JOIN addresses a_f ON a_f.id = m.from_address_id

JOIN invite_addresses ia_t ON ia_t.id = i.to_address_id
JOIN addresses a_t ON a_t.id = m.to_address_id

WHERE i.company_id = 1040345

AND i.status = 'claimed'
```

Comment: That did it! Follow-up question, if I want to show only the records that have an address discrepancy what sort of clause would I have to use? Is there a way to build on this conditional to implement this desired result?

Comment: You can wrap that inside another SELECT statement to pull out just the records that you want to show. The problem with changing this query to show only those records is that your SUM operations would change if we change what the query is returning.  If it were wrapped in another query it would look something like this:
'SELECT sub.id, sub.company_id, 
sub.status, 
sub.average_discrepancy,
sub.invites_from_address, 
moves_from_address,
moves_to_address,
sub.mover_first_name, 
sub.mover_last_name, 
sub.to_address_id
FROM
 ( -- Original Query goes here ) AS sub
WHERE sub.base_street != sub_f.base